# How to aggregate a field in BQL for complex query

Tags: acumatica

I have a BQL query joining three tables as follows:

```
foreach (PXResult<GLTran, Branch, xTACOpenSourceDetail> rec in
                                PXSelectJoin<GLTran,
                                             InnerJoin<Branch,
                                                 On<GLTran.branchID, Equal<Branch.branchID>>,
                                             InnerJoin<xTACOpenSourceDetail,
                                                 On<Branch.branchCD, Equal<xTACOpenSourceDetail.string03>,
                                                 And<xTACOpenSourceDetail.openSourceName, Equal<Constants.openSourceName>,
                                                 And<xTACOpenSourceDetail.dataID, Equal<Constants.privateer>>>>>>,
                                        Where<Branch.branchCD, NotEqual<Required<Branch.branchCD>>,
                                        And<GLTran.posted, Equal<True>,
                                        And<GLTran.ledgerID, Equal<Required<GLTran.ledgerID>>,
                                        And<GLTran.tranDate, GreaterEqual<Required<GLTran.tranDate>>>>>>,
                                        OrderBy<Asc<xTACOpenSourceDetail.string01, Asc<GLTran.batchNbr>>>>.Select(Base, osdBranch.String03, ledger.LedgerID, tacsmlm.Date01))
```

I want to add one aggregated field, namely the sum of the GLTran.CuryDebitAmt grouped by GLTran.BatNbr and Branch.BranchCD.

I can easily do this in SQL using the SUM OVER functionality as follows:

```
SELECT  SUM(GLTran.CuryDebitAmt) OVER (PARTITION BY GLTran.BatchNbr, Branch.BranchCD) as 'BatchTotal'
       ,GLTran.*
       ,Branch.*
       ,xTACOpenSourceDetail.*

FROM    GLTran
        Inner Join Branch
            On GLTran.branchID = Branch.branchID
            AND Branch.CompanyID = GLTran.CompanyID
        Inner Join xTACOpenSourceDetail
            On Branch.branchCD = xTACOpenSourceDetail.string03
            And xTACOpenSourceDetail.openSourceName = 'TAC FM Map Company Branch'
            And xTACOpenSourceDetail.dataID = 'Privateer'
            AND xTACOpenSourceDetail.CompanyID = GLTran.CompanyID


Where   Branch.branchCD <> '000 0000'
        And GLTran.posted = 1
        And GLTran.ledgerID = 6
        And GLTran.tranDate >= '08/03/2017'
        AND GLTran.CompanyID = 2

Order
By      xTACOpenSourceDetail.string01 ASC
        ,GLTran.batchNbr ASC
```

...but I have no idea how to add this single summed field in BQL.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use a `PXSelectGroupBy` and in your Aggreate for the BQL indicate which fields will "SUM" their values. Any field not called out will be the MAX value.

If you search `SUM<` in the Acumatica source you can find plenty of BQL examples. Here is a BQL Example from `ARPaymentEntry`. Only two (`curyAdjdAmt` & `adjAmt`) fields will contain a SUM while all other fields returned will be the MAX.

```
SOAdjust other = PXSelectGroupBy<SOAdjust,
    Where<SOAdjust.voided, Equal<False>,
        And<SOAdjust.adjdOrderType, Equal<Required<SOAdjust.adjdOrderType>>,
        And<SOAdjust.adjdOrderNbr, Equal<Required<SOAdjust.adjdOrderNbr>>,
        And<
            Where<SOAdjust.adjgDocType, NotEqual<Required<SOAdjust.adjgDocType>>, 
            Or<SOAdjust.adjgRefNbr, NotEqual<Required<SOAdjust.adjgRefNbr>>>>>>>>,
    Aggregate<GroupBy<SOAdjust.adjdOrderType,
        GroupBy<SOAdjust.adjdOrderNbr, 
        Sum<SOAdjust.curyAdjdAmt, 
        Sum<SOAdjust.adjAmt>>>>>>.Select(this, adj.AdjdOrderType, adj.AdjdOrderNbr, adj.AdjgDocType, adj.AdjgRefNbr);
```

Another alternative solution for your question would be to create a `PXProjection` which could be the sum by group values which you then in your regular select include the projection table vs the base table in your BQL. I don't know the performance benefits vs one or the other - just another option.

Comment: Thanks, Brendan.. ;D